# Error running Flutter App

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

I am developing an app on Flutter, but when I run to emulate it in the emulator IntelliJIdea gives me the following error:

`Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
    Ignoring bootsnap-1.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.1
    Ignoring byebug-10.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 10.0.2
        [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:`

```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    [0m
Ignoring ffi-1.9.25 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.25
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Ignoring msgpack-1.2.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine msgpack --version 1.2.4
Ignoring puma-3.12.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 3.12.0
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.13 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.13

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

`Error running pod install`

`Error launching application on iPhone X.`

Can anyone help with suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use "flutter run" command? I believe somehow another command is running. I believe your project is configured wrongly.

Comment: @yamin thanks for your suggestions, no I am trying to run flutter from IntelliJIDEA

Comment: @Shahsayyad Could you try `flutter run`? (and add the result of that to your question, best with `-v` for verbose output, which will most likely show the error)

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I did something and the Cocoapod error stopped. I uncommented  `#use_frameworks!` in Podfile and the error stopped and Android Studio gave me a build. The application is running smoothly but I am worried that this should not create additional unseen bugs.

Comment: Friends any idea on how to use video in-line in a Flutter app?

Comment: @Shahsayyad So please, either delete the question or provide your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this particular problem, by uncommenting `use_frameworks` in the Podfile.